# What's different between TFServing and KFServing on KubeFlow

Tags: tensorflow, model, tensorflow-serving, kubeflow

TFServin and KFServing both deploy the model on Kubeflow, and let users easy to use the model as a service, don't need to know detail about Kubernetes, hiding the infra layers.

- TFServing is from TensorFlow, it can also run on Kubeflow or standalone. [TFserving on kubeflow](https://www.kubeflow.org/docs/components/serving/tfserving_new/)
- KFServing is from Kubeflow, which can support multiple frameworks like PyTorch, TensorFlow, MXNet, etc. [KFServing](https://www.kubeflow.org/docs/components/serving/kfserving/)

My question is what's the main difference between these two projects.

If I want to launch my model in production, which should I use? which has better performance?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

KFServing is an abstraction on top of inferencing rather than a replacement. It seeks to simplify deployment and make inferencing clients agnostic to what inference server is doing the actual work behind the scenes (be it TF Serving, Triton (formerly TRT-IS), Seldon, etc). It does this by seeking agreement among inference server vendors on an inferencing dataplane specification which allows extra components (such as transformations and explainers) to be more pluggable.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, It makes sense to me. so I could say KFserving is built on top of TFserving